# How does social and sharing websites e.g. Facebook and Google+ handle security policies in code?

Tags: security, access-control, rbac, xacml, abac

I have heard that most websites use ad-hoc security. 
How is security policy specified and enforced in code?
E.g., only bob's friends may see his email address.
If the policy Intertwined throughout the code, how do they manage it as it is error prone. 
I have started developing a Information Flow Control package for web applications, just curious on what big companies use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this question is best suited for the [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) site.

Generally speaking, software development companies - not just websites - develop their own authorization logic ad-hoc using code (Java, C#... you name it).

There are a few companies / teams that have decoupled their business logic from their authorization logic. Doing so is called **externalizing authorization**. The field related to that is called **externalized authorization**.

There are several benefits to externalizing authorization:

- decouple business logic from authorization logic
- easier to maintain either codebase separately
- easier to audit
- centralized logic
- ...

There are several ways to achieve externalized authorization. Here are some examples:

- Spring Security (Java) gives you a way to express authorization logic using roles and annotations
- Claims-based authorization in .Net
- CanCan and CanCanCan in Ruby
- Flask in Python

All these approaches are specific to one given language. Some e.g. CanCan are policy-based. Others use a role-based approach.

Ideally, all companies and websites would use a technology-neutral approach based on policies. There is in fact a standard around such a 'thing'. It is called ABAC (attribute-based access control) and it uses policies written in XACML to express the access control logic.

The cool thing is that you could principally reuse these policies across Facebook, Yahoo, etc...

Comment: Users of an application are  A,B and C
Application has create methods to create a new document.
Users can assign permissions for the document they created.
Permissions to either view or edit.
Problem1:
User A of an application creates a private document and allows user B to view it. User C cannot view it. User B can collude with C and pass on the information to C, or can make the information public. How to solve this?

Comment: Problem2:
User A creates a public document and allows only B to edit it.
User C can read the document as it is public but can't write to it.
Again C can collude with B and create a new document which has the information to be inserted into A's Document. C gives this document read access to B.
Now B can read this new document and change A's document as B has edit permission. How to solve this?

Comment: @susheel, it would be better if in long term you accept that a person having a permission can delegate the same to anybody else. OAuth etc readily promote that behavior and overall it makes sense.

For your specific case, B might as well share his credentials with C or both can physically sit together to access the document.